# Regex to match a url pattern

Tags: regex

I need a regex pattern to match urls with a random token:

https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=TOKEN

This is what I have tried so far but its not returning a match

`/^https?:\/\/api.twitter.com\/oauth\/authenticate$\?oauth_token=./`

I have searched but posted regex solutions are so specific for the use case that I haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: I think the last bit should contain a * to match any number of chars after the end of pattern. No?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex:

```
/^https?:\/\/api.twitter.com\/oauth\/authenticate$\?oauth_token=./
```

Will match only single character after `oauth_token=` since you have `.`

You should use `.*$` as in:

```
/^https?:\/\/api.twitter.com\/oauth\/authenticate$\?oauth_token=.*$/
```

OR better:

```
/^https?:\/\/api.twitter.com\/oauth\/authenticate$\?oauth_token=[^&]*/
```

Which will match until end of string or next query parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^https?:\/\/api\.twitter\.com\/oauth\/authenticate\?oauth_token=(.*)/
```

I escaped the `.` characters in the url and also added the oauth token to a capture group so that it can be used for whatever you need to do with it.